# OpenERP error in adding purchase item line

Tags: odoo, keyerror

I inherited state in purchase.order - added Revision, Close.

The Revision state is to allow Purchase Order to revise the price or add item after approved.

But what happend is i can't add new item line in this added state, it'll always prompt the below error msg.

```
Environment Information :
System : Windows-post2008Server-6.1.7600
OS Name : nt
Operating System Release : post2008Server
Operating System Version : 6.1.7600
Operating System Architecture : 32bit
Operating System Locale : en_US.cp1252
Python Version : 2.6.5
OpenERP-Client Version : 6.1.1
Last revision No. & ID :Bazaar Package not Found !Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "netsvc.pyo", line 489, in dispatch
  File "service\web_services.pyo", line 599, in dispatch
  File "osv\osv.pyo", line 122, in wrapper
  File "osv\osv.pyo", line 176, in execute
  File "osv\osv.pyo", line 167, in execute_cr
  File "osv\orm.pyo", line 2947, in read
  File "osv\orm.pyo", line 3070, in _read_flat
KeyError: 10340
```

After I researched I found out that it only happened to meet this error if we're adding a new item line beyond the state provided by the core.

I tried add in done & approve state, it allows me, but not in my revision or close state.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you link to what you found during your research, we might be able to help you better.